# Sorting numerically with sort

Tags: unix, sorting

I have a logfile with entries on the following form that I want to sort numerically on the ID number field.

```
2011-10-06 08:13:48 ID_39 message1
2011-10-06 09:13:5s ID_239 message2
```

I have tried to accomplish this with the `sort` command but I don't seem to get the keys right. Sorting with `sort -b -k 3` just sort things alphabetically and `-n` (numeric sort) does not seem to help.

How do I go from this

```
ID_394
ID_65
ID_9
ID_99
```

To this?

```
ID_9
ID_65
ID_99
ID_394
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sort -t _ -k 2 -n`, which means: separate fields by `_`, sort numerically by second field.

Answer (score 1):

Found out that also `sort -b -k 3.4 -n` did the trick. With `-b` for ignoring leading blanks, `-k 3.4` to sort for the third field, from the fourth letter and `-n` for numerically.